# (PHP) Sending mail with php's Mail function adds new lines every 990 characters. How to workaround

Tags: php, email

I have the following problem:

Using the PHP mail() function i send mails around.
But every so often the damn sendmail adds newlines to the message (Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8).

Reading http://proquest.safaribooksonline.com/1565928393/ch20-77125 i figured out that this L= parameter is not set in sendmail. But i have no access to the mail server.

Is there a way ( By setting mail headers or something ) to skip the adding of these new line characters in the body of the mail )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I recommence to use a mailer class like [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), cause the build-in mail function don't match today's email standards, and you can easily configure the class for your needs.